# Prefix (stackify) + Web Api + MVC + EF 5 não está monitorando querys

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

Boa Tarde. Pessoal, não estou conseguindo utilizar o Prefix (stackify) + Web Api + MVC 4 + EF 5, pois o mesmo não está conseguindo monitorar as querys realizadas e realizar o retorno das informações. Na camada de Web Api estão os acessos ao banco da aplicação e as configurações do Prefix estão instaladas lá. Há alguma configuração extra a se fazer além da descrita no proprio site da stackify ? Obrigado.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Olhando para o seu traço, parece que você está batendo um auto aplicativo hospedado na porta 22788. Você pode confirmar isso é um auto hospedado site? Em outras palavras, não um IIS ou IIS Exress servido site. No momento prefixo não pode monitorar um site auto-hospedado. Eu acredito que ele está sendo trabalhado. Se você pode mudar a hospedagem para um IIS ou IIS Express para uso com o prefixo, essas consultas SQL se tornará visível. Agora eles estão por trás do site api na porta 22788. Desculpe-me, mas o original aqui é Inglês. Por favor culpar Traduz Google para qualquer má gramática ou má interpretação.

Comment: Bom Dia. Não é um site auto-hospedado. Web Api e MVC carregam no mesmo IIS Express. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Eu estou supondo que a sua aplicação não é auto hospedado como danatcofo disse , provavelmente usando IIS Express?

Você disse que as consultas de banco de dados são feitas na camada de API? Você precisa olhar para essas solicitações da web individuais para ver as consultas. Prefixo não irá atualmente mostrar-lhe o que aconteceu em várias solicitações do IIS que poderiam ser vários aplicativos ou servidores.

(Translated with Google)

Comment: Bom Dia. Não é um site auto-hospedado. Web Api e MVC carregam no mesmo IIS Express. Obrigado.